# Materializecss data-length not working in react

Tags: reactjs, materialize

This is my app component rendering on the screen but data-length attribute passed to the input field is not working else is working just perfectly fine.
You can check is truly easily on the offical docs of materialize css :- https://materializecss.com/text-inputs.html

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import M from "materialize-css";

class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    M.AutoInit();
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div class="row">
        <form class="col s12">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s6">
              <input id="input_text" type="text" data-length="10" />
              <label for="input_text">Input text</label>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="input-field col s12">
              <textarea
                id="textarea2"
                class="materialize-textarea"
                data-length="120"
              ></textarea>
              <label for="textarea2">Textarea</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case of React, whenever we use some kind of third party library or framework then we need to use `componentDidMount()` for initializing the js components provided by them.

There are few things which are different from materialize docs -

- Importing `import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";`
- Initialization in `componentDidMount`
- Using `maxLength` attribute instead of `data-length`.

[Codesandbox working demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-text-input-t11q7).

For other components, you can check [Reactize](https://reactize.herokuapp.com)

**Code**

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import M from "materialize-css";
import "materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css";

class Counter extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();

    this.state = {
      text: ""
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    let input = document.getElementById("input_text");
    M.CharacterCounter.init(input);
  }

  onTextChange = event => {
    this.setState({
      text: event.target.value
    });
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="row">
        <form className="col s12">
          <div className="row">
            <div className="input-field col s6">
              <input
                id="input_text"
                type="text"
                maxLength="10"
                onChange={this.onTextChange}
                value={this.state.text}
              />
              <label htmlFor="input_text">Input text</label>
            </div>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Counter;
```